# Listening for SharedPreferences changes in MainActivity

Tags: android, android-preferences, android-sharedpreferences

I am trying to listen `SharedPreferences` changes in the `MainActivity`. And update the values in the settings of the app. And the working code goes like:

```
private SharedPreferences SP, prefs;
SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener mListener;
SP = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext());

mListener = new SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener() {
    public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences prefs, String key) {

        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Key changed: "+key, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
};

SP.registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(mListener);
```

But when I try to change the key value like this. It says can not resolve `findPreference` method. I tried doing it using context but still the error persists.

```
private SharedPreferences SP, prefs;
SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener mListener;
SP = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext());

mListener = new SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener() {
    public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences prefs, String key) {

            if (key.equals("username")) {
                Preference pref = findPreference(key);
                pref.setDefaultValue(prefs.getString(key, "bob"));    }
};
SP.registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(mListener);
```

How can we import the method definition in `MainActivity`. Please tell if the way I am changing value here, if correct?

Settings.java

```
import android.preference.PreferenceActivity;
import android.preference.PreferenceFragment;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class Settings extends PreferenceActivity {



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(android.R.id.content, new MyPreferenceFragment()).commit();
    }

    public static class MyPreferenceFragment extends PreferenceFragment
    {
        PrefManager prefManager;
        @Override
        public void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);
        }
    }

}
```

preferences.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <EditTextPreference android:title="Your Name"
        android:key="username"
        android:summary="Please provide your username">
    </EditTextPreference>


</PreferenceScreen>
```

I basically want to update the Preference in the settings page whenever `SharedPreferences` of key "`username`" is getting changed in the code.

Comment: Why do you expect it to know what `findPreference` is? You didn't declare it (not in the code you have shown at least). What are you trying to do in the first place? If you can tell me more, I might be able to help you.

Comment: As Sweeper said post your findPreference code. Anysays just use the prefs var passed in the method to modify it.

Comment: @Sweeper I have added my settings.java and preferences.xml code. And last line tells what I want to achieve in MainActivity.java

Answer (score 2):

> You must implement `PreferenceActivity` in your activity

Add `extends PreferenceActivity` after your activity name and then import it's namespace:

```
public class MainActivity extends PreferenceActivity {
  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
      ...
   }
}
```

For more info look at http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/PreferenceActivity.html

**EDITED**

**Use the following code:**

```
public class Settings extends PreferenceActivity  {

    private SharedPreferences SP;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(android.R.id.content, new MyPreferenceFragment()).commit();

        SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener mListener;
        SP = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext());

    }

    public static class MyPreferenceFragment extends PreferenceFragment implements
            SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener{
        @Override
        public void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);
        }

        @Override
        public void onResume() {
            super.onResume();
            getPreferenceScreen().getSharedPreferences()
                    .registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);
        }

        @Override
        public void onPause() {
            super.onPause();
            getPreferenceScreen().getSharedPreferences()
                    .unregisterOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);
        }

        public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences prefs, String key) {
            if (key.equals("username")) {
                Preference pref = findPreference(key);
                pref.setDefaultValue(prefs.getString(key, "bob"));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I did `MainActivity extends PreferenceActivity` and now `registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener` becomes an unknown class. And `findPreference` is depricated. See the extra details I added in question, if you get some clue. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Okay but where are we listening? OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener or how do I use this class in my app? You can see my settings.java has some of this code already. Do I have to add this code there or how?

Comment: Listener is implemented in the Settings activity, Just replace this with your Settings activity code

Comment: It crashes on opening the settings activity. `getPreferenceScreen(), findPreference()` are depricated. Are you sure that onResume, onPause, onShare... would be in settings class? Error is `Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.SharedPreferences android.preference.PreferenceScreen.getSharedPreferences()' on a null object reference`

Comment: Hey, I just edited the `settings.java` code in your answer. That works for me without error. But the values are not getting updated even when `SharedPreferences` are getting modified in the code. I seriously doubt that we need to implement listening part (see my question) somewhere. I did try but I am getting one or the other error while compilation. Do you have any idea, how  can I call the `mListener = new SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener()`

Comment: Hey, I suggest you this example :) Visit [Android Preferences with onchange Preference Listener Example](http://www.tutorialsbuzz.com/2014/02/android-preference-example-onchange-listener.html)

Comment: Sure. I will go through. Understand. And post answer that would work for this kind of situation. Thanks Ahmad :)